# Get ID of row in aggregate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following query to get me the values corresponding with the latest date:

```
SELECT MAX(RowAddedDate), X, Y
FROM dbo.MyTable
GROUP BY X, Y
```

This is fine, but I need to get the ID of each row in this query.  If I add the ID though, I get everything as the ID needs to be in the `GROUP BY`.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use window (ranking). functions for this:

```
WITH ct AS
  ( SELECT X, Y, RowAddedDate, ID,
           Rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY X, Y
                                   ORDER BY RowAddedDate DESC)
    FROM dbo.MyTable
  )
sELECT X, Y, RowAddedDate, ID
FROM ct 
WHERE Rn = 1 ;
```

If multiple rows have the same date with same X and Y, all of them will be returned due to the `DENSE_RANK()`.

If you want only one, you can replace it with `ROW_NUMBER()` and adjust the `ORDER BY` to control which of the tied rows will be returned.

As for efficiency, an index on `(X, Y, RowAddedDate) INCLUDE (ID)` would help.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a window MAX() to achieve the result in a way that is semantically very close to the one you have discovered but does not involve a join:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  X,
  Y,
  RowAddedDate
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      MaxRowAddedDate = MAX(RowAddedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY X, Y)
    FROM
      dbo.MyTable
  ) AS derived
WHERE
  RowAddedDate = MaxRowAddedDate
;
```

The maximum values of *RowAddedDate* per *X, Y* are returned alongside non-aggregated values. You just filter on the max values to get the rows you want.

Answer (score 1):

OK, had a brain flash as soon as I posted this.  Still, answer might help someone.

It is possible that the combination of `MAX(RowAddedDate), X, Y` in the query isn't unique, therefore the query can't be guaranteed to return a single ID per row.

As such, I will have to `JOIN` the table on itself with those three values as the join condition.